# Visual Studio Code проверка прохождения теста

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image: VS CODE]

На курсах rolling scopes выполняю тесты по JavaScript. Суть первых четырех заданий – перевод градусы Цельсия в Фаренгейты.  Оформить всё нужно в VS Code. Связка VS Code+Node.js+Git. Первые четыре задания в файле test.js (в правом окне), решение нужно написать в файле index.js (в левом окне), проверка правильности выполнения через терминал, командой npm test. 
Функцию перевода написал, а что дальше?  Что нужно делать с файлом test.js?

В VS Code плохо разбираюсь, совсем не понимаю суть работы в данной программе.  Помогите решить первое задание. Вкратце объясните, что нужно делать дальше.

Спасибо всем кто уделит время на разъяснение столь очевидного.

Comment: Попробуйте написать в консоли npm test

Comment: Прописывал (npm test ). Результат (если вкратце) 0 пройденных из 4. 
Но все равно спасибо.

Comment: Ну значит, ваша функция не правильно рассчитывает результат.

Comment: точка показывает. что файл index.js - не сохранен после изменений.

Comment: Всем спасибо разобрался -) Нужна так:  module.exports = function warmup(temperature) {
 
  var fahrenheit = (9*temperature)/5+32; 
  return fahrenheit; 
};